# How to avoid recording history for redirects made using WebExtension webRequest API

Tags: firefox, browser-history, firefox-addon-webextensions, http-redirect, web-extension

Below is source code for a simple web browser add-on that redirects all `example.com` requests to `example.org` using WebExtension's `webRequest` API. I have tested the extension in Mozilla Firefox.

`manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Example Redirector",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://example.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "example-redirector.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

`example-redirector.js`:

```js
function redirectHandler(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  return {
    redirectUrl: "https://example.org" +  url.pathname + url.search
  };
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  redirectHandler,
  {urls: ["*://example.com/*"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

When I enter `https://example.com`, I will be redirected to `https://example.org`. The HTTP headers sent to `https://example.org` is as if I had entered `https://example.org` in the address bar, instead of the HTTP headers that are normally sent by Firefox during a `301` or `302` redirect. However, `https://example.com` appears in my browser history right before `https://example.org`. How do I avoid this? I only want Firefox to record `https://example.org` in history when I am redirected to it by the web browser extension.

Firefox version: 102.10.0esr (64-bit). OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

Comment: It may be a bug. The workaround might be to use browser.history API to delete the URL.